# Query about inclination in Earth's axis of rotation

Tags: earth-rotation

Earth revolves around the Sun in a elliptical path, situated on one of the Sun's focal points. If Earth is considered as a large body with mass attracted towards the Sun's core causing its revolution and rotation, what is the reason behind an angle of inclination of 23°30' that Earth makes with the plane of solar system? Theoretically, if Sun's gravitational pull drives Earth into revolution and spin, then the rotational axis should be perpendicular to plane of the solar system.

Comment: the spin of the planets and the sun is left over energy from the creation of the solar system,this question had probably been a better fit over at astronomy as i think they could better explain this.

Comment: This question, asked by someone else, has been answered on SE Physics: [What is the scientific reason for the inclination of earth's rotation axis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76600/what-is-the-scientific-reason-for-the-inclination-of-earths-rotation-axis). The answer appears to be, we don't know, but a collision is a probable cause.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Axial Tilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt) may be of interest to you. Mars has a tilt of 25.19 deg, Saturn 26.73 deg, Neptune 28.32 deg, Uranus, 82.23 deg, Pluto 54.47 deg. Even the Sun has a tilt of 7.25 deg. Venus has a tilt of 2.64 deg, but because it spins in the opposite to Earth & most of the other planets it could be argued its tilt is 182.64 deg.